# pandas dataframe mean value with two groupby: one by month, another by a parameter

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

A dataframe with data of dates (in form of yymmdd), names and record, as below:

```
     date name  record
0  200104    A      16
1  200105    B      20
2  200105    A      18
3  200106    B      22
4  200201    A      14
5  200201    B      17
6  200202    A      18
7  200203    B      19
```

I need to group by months and name, taking the mean of record, to have result looks like:

```
Jan  A  17
     B  21
Feb  A  16
     B  18
```

Please could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html) and the aggregate mean:

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y%m%d').dt.month_name().rename('month')

df = df.groupby([m,'name'], sort=False)['record'].mean().reset_index()
print (df)
      month name  record
0   January    A      17
1   January    B      21
2  February    A      16
3  February    B      18
```

Or if necessary select only first 3 letters of months:

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y%m%d').dt.month_name().str[:3].rename('month')
df = df.groupby([m,'name'], sort=False)['record'].mean().reset_index()
print (df)

  month name  record
0   Jan    A      17
1   Jan    B      21
2   Feb    A      16
3   Feb    B      18
```

Comment: sorry I need to explain more: date are in form of yymmdd.

Comment: @Brom - Edited, solution with correct order if all  next months

Comment: If I only use January, February, could I not use the `list` cats?

Comment: Brilliant! It sorts according to months. If I have data from May last year to Apr this year, it will begin with May, instead of alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert `date` to month names and groupby:

```
(df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%y%m%d').dt.strftime('%b'),
            'name'])['record']
  .mean())
```

Output:

```
 date  name
Jan   A       17
      B       21
Feb   A       16
      B       18
Name: record, dtype: int64
```

Comment: sorry the date is in form of yymmdd, so there should have only average of Jan and Feb